# Rename refactoring for PHP in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Is there a rename refactoring for PHP in Visual Studio Code? It is the only thing that stops me from fully move from NetBeans to VSC. Renaming is very importat for me (not search/replace).

When I rename local variable (let say $sum) it should change the name only in the scope where that local variable was defined, not all variables named $sum in the same file or across all files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45724395/3395469

Comment: Ah... Well, your welcome. Hope someone has an answer for you. =)

Comment: Do you have any feedback on what was posted?
That is the best way to help others help you.

Answer (score 1):

I am listing a few sources here.

1. A cross-post in SO by the same asker, at a very near date [Rename refactoring for PHP in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731353/rename-refactoring-for-php-in-visual-studio-code).
   [The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46731732/2707864) showed both approval in upvotes and "disapproval" in a comment, so YMMV.
2. [PHP IntelliSense](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-intellisense)
3. https://github.com/htintrinh/php-refactor-vscode
4. [Devsense](https://www.devsense.com/en), which claims to have [refactoring](https://docs.devsense.com/en/vscode/editor/refactoring).
5. [PHP Refactor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tintrinh.php-refactor)
6. [PHP Refactoring](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=marsl.vscode-php-refactoring)
7. [A list with possible options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_extensions-with-refactorings)

Answer (score 0):

Rename refactoring for PHP is provided through an extension.

[PHP Tools for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.phptools-vscode) provides rename refactoring, quick fixes, code actions, code formatting, code validation and more.

update: it is a paid extension, free for students

Comment: It is `paid` license

Comment: well, you can use "PHP Refactor Tool", it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Below are some free extensions that do refactoring for PHP:

- [PHP IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-intellisense)
- [PHP Refactor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tintrinh.php-refactor)
- [PHP Refactor Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=st-pham.php-refactor-tool)

I haven't used any of them, so cannot recommend one above the others.